# Android AlarmManager doesn't work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I searched on the forum but it works for others. What is wrong in my AlarmManager?
I want to call the CallDataSend class in every minute

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, CallDataSend.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (2 * 1000), pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

the CallDataSend class:

```
public final class CallDataSend extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm worked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

and xml file:

```
<receiver
        android:name="CallDataSend"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should make the receiver enabled before it can be instantiated by the system.

```
<receiver
        android:name="CallDataSend"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

You also have to name your receiver with *".YourClass"* instead of *"YourClass"* if that class is in the same package declared in your manifest's attributes or with *"YourCompletePackage.YourClass"* if it is not.

Ex:
in your case,

```
<receiver
    android:name=".CallDataSend"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

in another case,

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.CallDataSend"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```